# How can I customize Jasmine's directory structure?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

When using the Jasmine Rubygem, I find it extremely annoying that I have to conform to the generated directory structure which has a `javascripts` subfolder within the `spec` folder. I find it useless since I'm writing entirely in Javascript.

I find I can change this within the `public` folder by changing the generated `jasmine.yml`, however, this is not what I wanted since I still have to keep the `javascripts` folder with me.

Is there any way of customizing this folder structure?

Answer (score 5):

Here's how I did this with jasmine gem 1.0.2.1:

1) Customize the jasmine_config.rb file to override the simple_config_file method to point to the correct yml file path. This file is initially generated at spec/javascripts/support/jasmine_config.rb. As seen on the github source (https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine-gem/blob/v1.0.2.1/lib/jasmine/config.rb), the method is hardcoded to use:

```
def simple_config_file
  File.join(project_root, 'spec/javascripts/support/jasmine.yml')
end
```

I wanted to rename my 'spec' directory to 'test' so the top of my jasmine_config.rb file looks like this:

```
module Jasmine
  class Config
    def simple_config_file
      File.join(project_root, 'test/javascripts/support/jasmine.yml')
    end
  end
end
```

2) Force rake to load the config file. I did this by adding the line:

```
require 'test/javascripts/support/jasmine_config.rb'
```

immediately after requiring jasmine in my Rakefile.

3) Update jasmine.yml (also in the support folder) to indicate where your javascript test files live. My yml file now ends with this:

```
# EXAMPLE:
#
# spec_dir: spec/javascripts
#
spec_dir: test/javascripts
```

Of course, you need to adjust that path "test" to be what you want.

I think this approach should work with the latest version of the gem, but this approach will break in the future if they change the interface of that Config class.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2021, here's how to change the folder name when using the [`jasmine-browser-runner`](https://jasmine.github.io/setup/browser.html) with NodeJS.

Install jasmine and setup the project:

```
npm install --save-dev jasmine-browser-runner jasmine-core
npx jasmine-browser-runner init
```

Rename the `spec` folder to `test` and edit `jasmine-browser.json`:

```
"specDir": "test"
```

Run the tests with this command:

```
npx jasmine-browser-runner runSpecs --config=test/support/jasmine-browser.json
```